# Which language came first with parallel assignment?

Tags: programming-languages, history

When I discovered  that python has parallel assignment I thought is pretty cool.

Recently I discovered parallel assignment works also in ruby.

For people that don't know it: `x,y = y,x` in ruby, python this swaps x and y values .

Which language came first with parallel assignment, python? or was it other language?

Comment: This is called tuple unpacking in python, not parallel assignment.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Because they are separated by commas python treats x,y like being tuple?

Comment: I just discovered that in FireBug console [x,y]=[y,x] works too.

Comment: Exactly; a tuple on the right-hand side will be unpacked into a series of variables on the left, if the lengths match. The `y, x` value on the right is a tuple because of the comma.

Comment: PHP likewise has the more-verbose `list($a, $b) = array(1, 2)`

Comment: @EduardFlorinescu Javascript had parallel assignment for a while now, and quite a few other languages support the mechanism. Off the top of my head: C++, Lua, Perl, PowerShell, and there are probably a few others...

Comment: @YannisRizos In Chrome console that didn't work!

Comment: @YannisRizos It's called "destructuring assignment" in Javascript, and is [far from cross-browser](http://robertnyman.com/javascript/) - you can't rely on it unless Firefox is all you want to support..

Comment: @Izkata Yes, that's right. I don't keep up with Javascript browser support, I'm one of the very few lucky JS developers that don't have to care for implementations (my only front end code is on an intranet application and we get to chose our users' browser ;).

Comment: @YannisRizos In C++, Lua, Perl, PowerShell are they simillar?

Comment: Yes, the exception being C++. There is a Boost tuple class, and C++11 has a tuple type, but I haven't touched C++ in a while...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[CPL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPL_%28programming_language%29) introduced the feature in 1963, calling it simultaneous assignment. From D.W. Barron et al., "[The main features of CPL](http://comjnl.oxfordjournals.org/content/6/2/134.full.pdf)" (page 140):

> #### 24. Simultaneous assignment commands
>
> The general form of an assignment command can now be given. Normally this is an expression yielding an LH value, followed by :=, followed by an expression yielding an RH value. However, if an explicit list is written on the left-hand side then the right-hand side is either an explicit list, or a list expression; in the latter case the transfer function Members is automatically invoked. In this form the two explicit lists must contain the same number of members, and the command denotes a simultaneous assignment of each right-hand member to the corresponding left-hand member. Thus, if L is a list variable and a, b, c are real variables,
>
> L := a, b, c
>
> is an assignment to the list variable, while
>
> a, b, c := L
>
> a, b := b,a
>
> are simultaneous assignments.

Comment: Example near the bottom of this page: http://progopedia.com/language/cpl/